# Infer 'Sibling'-Type Relation in Protégé

Tags: owl, protege

I have a Class 'Smith' , Representing the Smith Family. Within are 4 Members, The Parents ; 'John_Smith' and 'Julie_Smith' , and the children; 'Jack_Smith' and 'Jill_Smith'. I have a Object property 'Is_Parent_Of', and it's inferred inverse property 'Is_Child_Of'. I am wondering if there is a way to infer a sibling relationship using these two properties?

I have a Property 'Has_Sibling' already in use to assign this manually which is an Symmetric, Transitive property but I can't find a way to fully infer the property.
I can sort of infer it using the DL Query function with a query like " Has_Parent value John_Smith and Has_Parent value Julie_Smith'

Comment: you could try a property chain axiom like `Is_Parent_Of o Is_Child_Of SubPropertyOf Has_Sibling` - without having specified the inverse relation in your ontology it would need 
 `Is_Parent_Of o inverse Is_Parent_Of SubPropertyOf Has_Sibling` - and you have to add another axiom to get the same for children as well - **but** those chains would relate each parent (resp. child) to itself, i.e.e you get `a Has_Sibling a`.

Comment: The other option would be to use an SWRL rule

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved it just by making a SWRL just as [@UninformedUser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744359/uninformeduser) mentioned.

A way to do this in Protégé is to go into Window -> Views -> Ontology Views -> Rules to open the Rules tab, and add the following rule:

```
Is_Child_Of(?a,?x), Is_Child_Of(?b,?x), DifferentFrom(?a,?b) -> Has_Sibling(?a,?b)
```

This rule states that if 'a' is child 'x', and 'b' is also child of 'x', and 'a' is not 'b' (to prevent it from being reflexive), then 'a' is sibling of 'b'. To make the atom DifferentFrom work, remember to state the Different Individuals in the Individuals tab.